# WebSite 503 Error on Real Site?

Tags: vb.net, http

```
Public Function GetIPInfo(ByVal IPNumb As String, ByVal GetInfo As String) As String
    Dim i1, i2 As Integer
    Dim s1, s2, s3 As String
    Dim IPCheckWebsite As String
    Dim WC As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    IPCheckWebsite = WC.DownloadString("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & IPNumb)
    For i1 = 1 To Len(IPCheckWebsite)
        s1 = Mid(IPCheckWebsite, 1, i1)
        If InStr(s1, GetInfo) > 0 Then
            s2 = Mid(IPCheckWebsite, i1 + 10)
            For i2 = 1 To Len(s2)
                s3 = Mid(s2, 1, i2)
                If InStr(s3, "<") > 0 Then
                    IPCheckWebsite = Mid(s3, 1, i2 - 1)
                    GoTo Done
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Done:
        Return IPCheckWebsite
    End Function

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.Add("IP: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "IP:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Hostname: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "Hostname:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("ISP: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "ISP:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Organization: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "Organization:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Services: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "Services:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Country: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "Country:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("State/Region: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "State/Region:"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("City: " & GetIPInfo(TextBox3.Text, "City:"))
End Sub
```

It says the website server has a 503 Error, But the site is up and works fine. Am I Doing Something Wrong?

```
Dim WC As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    IPCheckWebsite = WC.DownloadString("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & IPNumb)
```

specifically This code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that whatismyipaddress.com probably has measures in place to try and block people from doing precisely what you are doing.

They are returning a 503 response which means "service unavailable".

If you are sure that you should be able to scrape their site with a bot, you'll need to contact the administrator of whatismyaddress.com for their help.

Another issue with your code is that it appears you are fetching their page 8 times for one button click, which is probably not good etiquette (unless you know that WC.DownloadString is caching the response, I guess).

Comment: It was that the fact i kept hitting it 8 times at once. The Site did not like that, I Fixed it and using: Public Sub GetSiteSource(ByVal IPNumb As String)
        Dim URL As String = "http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & IPNumb
        Dim client As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim data As System.IO.Stream = client.OpenRead(URL)
        Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(data)
        IPCheckWebsite = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Sub instead